# Open multiple webview into single activity

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I want open webView like below image but unable to achieve.
[image]
here is my code.anybody can give me suggestion how can i show the multiple webview into one activity.Thanks in advance.

WebView.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
>

<WebView 
android:id="@+id/webView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
/>
<WebView 
android:id="@+id/webView2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
/>
<WebView 
android:id="@+id/webView3"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
/>
<WebView 
android:id="@+id/webView4"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

WebViewActivity.java

```
  public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {  

   private WebView webView1,webView2,webView3,webView4;  

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);  

    webView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);  
    webView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
    webView2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);  
    webView2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
    webView3 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView3);  
    webView3.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
    webView4 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView4);  
    webView4.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
    webView1.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");  
    webView2.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");  
    webView3.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");  
    webView4.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");  



   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just trying to show how you can achieve this. Creating a fully functioning chrome like UI need a lot hard work and experience, simply I don't have.

In my answer I tried to rotate a webview for creating 3d view.To get this in your real code you have to create this effect in your java code.

one_fifth.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:background="#ee0000"
        android:rotationX="-30" />

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:background="#450000"
        android:rotationX="-30" />

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:background="#ee4560"
        android:rotationX="-30" />

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:background="#ee2300"
        android:rotationX="-30" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and java code is here
MainClass.java

```
public class MainClass extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.one_fifth);
        LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        for(int i=0;i<linearLayout.getChildCount();i++)
        {
            WebView view=(WebView) linearLayout.getChildAt(i);

            view.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Final output is look like this]